# How to set view protection in the beginning by .htaccess in the XAMPP for sub directories?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, xampp

I have local website(php) on xampp and I want  set user password login protection as shown as

[image]

I set in .htaccess  :

```
Options -Indexes
allow from 127.0.0.0
AuthName "Password Protected Area" 
AuthUserFile /htaccess/.htpasswd 
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

And in .htpasswd I set:

```
user:$2y$10$L7cqU20P.fbfHwIL7cqU20PsvrhnN.Pb1rAxR50y
```

But I after enter user password I get this error:
[image]

I use [this](https://imalabya.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/set-a-authentication-password-in-xampp-using-htpasswd/) but not work.
When I enter  `http:127.0.0.1/hi` that work but when I enter sub directory not work (`http:127.0.0.1/hi/test1`) and give 500 error .

Comment: First of all, check the error log - that is _always_ the first thing you do, when you get a 500 error!

Comment: And then go read what https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile has to say about the file path. I doubt that yours is actually correct here.

Comment: i cant go to directory and no problem,  but sub directory give me 500 error code.

Comment: _“but sub directory give me 500 error code”_ - and what were you just told to go and do first in such a case then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was OK but I do not know why an .htaccess empty file  was created in all my sub folders when I delete them work correctly.